# react-native Navigator.NavigationBar - where are the docs?

Tags: react-native

I've seen a few examples online using `Navigator.NavigationBar`. It looks handy but I don't know how to use it. Are there docs anywhere?

Comment: I haven't seen any docs for it but I found the source code for the component here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBar.js . This should help at least in implementing it an a basic way.

Answer (score 15):

Officially there is no guide Navigator.Navigation Bar. But looking on the internet you can find examples of how it works. Below is an example that I used for one of my projects.

```js
var PageOne = require('./pageone'),
    PageTwo = require('./pagetwo');


var NavigationBarRouteMapper = { 
  LeftButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.leftButton }</Text>
    )
  },
  Title: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.title }</Text>
    )
  },
  RightButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.rightButton }</Text>
    )
  }
}

var App = React.createClass({

  renderScene: function( route, nav ) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'PageOne':
        return <PageOne navigator={ nav } title={ "PageOne" } />
      case 'PageTwo':
        return <PageTwo navigator={ nav } leftButton={ "Back" } title={ "PageTwo" } />;
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ id: 'PageOne', title: 'PageOne' }}
        renderScene={ this.renderScene }
        configureScene={( route ) => {
          if ( route.sceneConfig ) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
          }
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
        }}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar 
            routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper } 
          />
        } 
      />
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: I've tried setting up my `renderScene` like this, but that did not work. The `leftButton`, `rightButton` and `title` parameters need to be passed in the *route* object, not in the component. Probably because your `PageOne` and `PageTwo` components relay the parameters when calling `navigator.push`

Answer (score 0):

I would also add to checkout the UI Explorer in the examples that show how to use it. [UIExplorer Navigator](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/Navigator) -

EDIT: React native has done a good job updating their docs. Here is the documentation to the navigator: [navigator docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)

UPDATE: Do your self a favor and use something like react-navigation. Those links will be broken because of MANY updates to RN.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

**Updates on 2017**: [Official documentation of React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) recommend using `react-navigation` library.

Setup variable:

```
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});
```

Example:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Read the official documentation for detailed information.