# How Does The React-Native Navigation Bar Work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigationbar

So I've been trying to get the react-native navigation i've looked a many examples online, but i still don't quite understand what i'm doing wrong.

My example is loosely based on another one i found on Stackoverflow:

[react-native Navigator.NavigationBar - where are the docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680794/react-native-navigator-navigationbar-where-are-the-docs)

I'm unable to figure out how to pass variables into the navigation bar for value like 'route.title' and 'route.leftButton'.

When i first load the app it all seems fine. It is getting the data from the Navigator.initialRoute property, but if i click on the left or right buttons in debug mode and i inspect the value of route, i can see it is an object that only holds a single property 'id' which is set to 'undefined'.

i have looked at the documentation and i think it might be too brief for me to fully understand. any guidance on this is appreciated.

thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
    LeftButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigator.pop()}>
                <Text>{ route.leftButton }TestLeft</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    },
    Title: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
        return(
            <Text>{ route.title }</Text>
        )
    },
    RightButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
        debugger;
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigator.push({id: 'PageTwo', title:'page222'})}>
                <Text>{ route.rightButtonAction }TestRight</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}

var PageOne = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 1</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
});

var PageTwo = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
                <Text>you are on page 2</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
});

class testApp extends Component {

    renderScene( route, nav ) {
        switch (route.id) {
            case 'PageOne':
                return <PageOne navigator={ nav } leftButton={ "Back" } title={ "PageOne111" } rightButtonAction={"PageTwo"} />
            case 'PageTwo':
                return <PageTwo navigator={ nav } leftButton={ "Back" } title={ "PageTwo222" } rightButtonAction={"PageOne"} />;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{ id: 'PageOne', title: 'PageOne' }}
                renderScene={ this.renderScene }
                configureScene={( route ) => {
                  if ( route.sceneConfig ) {
                    return route.sceneConfig;
                  }
                  return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
                }}
                navigationBar={
                  <Navigator.NavigationBar
                    routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper }
                  />
                }
              />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testApp', () => testApp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this article as it appears to be very informative. It is from February of this year, so some of it might be out of date already.

https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.45yr7nycr

I think that it basically comes down to having access to the route and navigation properties in the functions of `NavigationBarRouteMapper` and using those properties to customise the values.

(code reproduced from the article, in case it vanishes)

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(index > 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor="transparent"
          onPress={() => { if (index > 0) { navigator.pop() } }}>
          <Text style={ styles.leftNavButtonText }>Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>)
    } 
    else { return null }
  },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (route.onPress) return (
      <TouchableHighlight
         onPress={ () => route.onPress() }>
         <Text style={ styles.rightNavButtonText }>
              { route.rightText || 'Right Button' }
         </Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>)
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return <Text style={ styles.title }>MY APP TITLE</Text>
  }
};
```

Hopefully this will help you move in the right direction.

Comment: thanks. that article looks comprehensive. i'll update my comment with the solution if i get it to work.

Comment: im still not quite understanding the navigation bar. i understand to push the data into the navigation (which wours anywhere in the scene pages, but still not sure when the variables in the renderScene() function isnt available as properties of the route object in NavigationBarRouteMapper.