# Inside React Native <Navigator/>, how do I reference the current route.name being passed in?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

In < Navigator />, based on the current route.name being passed in, I want to do the following, but I am getting an error: 'route is not defined'. Why is that so? And how should I go about doing so?

```
<Navigator
...
navigationBar={<Navigator.NavigationBar style={route.name == 'Home' ? styles.homeNavBar : styles.normalNavBar} .../>
/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`route` is not defined because that variable is not given to you anywhere in this code. If you want to change the styling, but still use the NavigationBar, you're better off writing it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697459/1487687

Your `NavigationBarRouteMapper` object will have the route injected to each function:

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = { 
  LeftButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.leftButton }</Text>
    )
  },
  Title: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.title }</Text>
    )
  },
  RightButton: function( route, navigator, index, navState ){
    return(
      <Text>{ route.rightButton }</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

If you need to style the bar directly, you're better off making your own navigation bar component. I'd take a look at the source for this one to get an idea: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar

Comment: I'm trying to style the nav bar itself, such as change its color, and not its components. Would there be a way around it with my approach? Like  if on a particular route, the nav bar is blue, and on another nav bar, it would be red.

Comment: Checking to see if you've received my last comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Looks like the only way is to wrap the navigation bar, and use redux or some other way to get the current route: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2560#issuecomment-139919812. This issue talks about using a flux based solution https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3926#issuecomment-154688017.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current route like so: navigator.getCurrentRoutes() where navigator is the Navigator object. In your example, you probably will have to use this.getCurrentRoutes or reference it like the following link suggests:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: Here is a gist. Do you know what I am doing wrong? The navBar style still isn't updating even if the Home component is passed in.